Flutter - No implementation found for method "sendCustomData" on channel com.mobile.app/customChannel
for a job I need to call Custom MethodChannel and get information from Android native code, but I get the error "No implementation found for method "sendCustomData" on channel com.mobile.app/customChannel".
My code is below:
    class myService implements UserDataCollector {
  static final myService _singleton = myService._internal();

  factory myService() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  final _platform = const MethodChannel('com.mobile.app/customChannel');
  myService._internal();

  Future<void> sendCustomData(
      {required String dataType, required Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    if (RemoteConfigController.sendCustomDataToVeloxity) {
      final encodedJson = jsonEncode(data);
      _platform.invokeMethod("sendCustomData", {
        "customData": encodedJson,
        "customDataType": dataType,
      });
    }
  }
}

Android :
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.mobile.app/customChannel";


    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler { call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result ->
                if (call.method == "sendCustomData") {
                    result.success(true)
                } else {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
    }
}

Use
 await veloxityService.sendCustomData(dataType: "send_data", data: {""});

note : Namings are examples.
Thanks.

Looks very much like your code tries to invoke initMethod, such as _platform.invokeMethod("initMethod", ... ). Are you sure that sendCustomData is only method ever called in your code ?

The problem was caused by incorrect android:name naming.
android:name="com.app.MainActivity"

